# Parsing and changing nested XMLs in java

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I have following XML file format and I have to add another *car* tag with *id* number that follows previous one (in this case 3):

```
<vehicles>
     <cars>
         <car id="1">
             <name>ferrari</name>
         </car>
         <car id="2">
             <name>lamborgini</name>
         </car>
     </cars>
</vehicles>
```

I have already found a solution for adding another element and it looks like this:

```
try {
        File inputFile = new File(file);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("car");
        Element car= doc.createElement("car");
        car.setAttribute("id", "3");
        Element node = doc.createElement("name");
        node.setTextContent("audi");
        car.appendChild(node);
        nList.item(0).getParentNode().appendChild(car);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(inputFile);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now I have three problems:

- how to add new "car" with correct id to the end (not hard coded) with the simplest solution possible
- formating (not so important): how to include elements with the same formatting as existing ones (tabs, white spaces)
- how to check if "cars" tag already exists

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you already have all car nodes as list in nList, traverse the list from last item.

Once you find a node of type Element stop it. Get the attribute id value for that node.

Your next node id will be +1 of your newly found id value

Comment: How can i traverse the list from last item?